# What are vector fields given by the partial derivatives of coordinate functions?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, lie-derivative, tangent-spaces

I am using Sean Carroll's book "Spacetime and Geometry" to learn about differential topology from a physics point of view. After introducing vectors on a manifold, he defines the commutator of two vector fields as ([Google books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=PTGdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=Note%20that%20since%20partials%20commute,%20the%20commutator%20of%20the%20vector%20fields%20given%20by%20the%20partial%20derivatives%20of%20coordinate%20functions,%20%7Ba%C2%B5%7D,%20always%20vanishes.&source=bl&ots=grS3o2vNBJ&sig=ACfU3U2iVQcouRtugAJrlQNEcuLHqOxm3A&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Note%20that%20since%20partials%20commute%2C%20the%20commutator%20of%20the%20vector%20fields%20given%20by%20the%20partial%20derivatives%20of%20coordinate%20functions%2C%20%7Ba%C2%B5%7D%2C%20always%20vanishes.&f=false), p. 67)

$$ [X, Y](f) = X(Y(f))-Y(X(f)) \tag{2.20} $$

At the bottom of the page, he states

> *Note that since partials commute, the commutator of the vector fields given by the partial derivatives of coordinate functions, $\{\partial_\mu\}$, always vanishes.*

I don't understand this statement. As far as I understand, for a given chart and curve with parameter $\lambda$ on the manifold, we can write a vector as

$$  X = X^\mu \hat e _{(\mu)}\quad\to\quad \frac{d}{d\lambda} = \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\partial_\mu \tag{2.16} $$

where I used the coordinate basis. But what does the author mean by "*the vector fields given by the partial derivatives of coordinate functions*"? How would one calculate the commutator in this case?

Comment: He means the vector fields $\partial_\mu$. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin So is the vector field then $X=\partial^\mu \partial_\mu$? How can the vector field itself be a partial?

Comment: No, the vector field is $1\cdot\partial_\mu$, no summation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector fields he is referring to are those of the form $\partial_{\mu_0}$ for fixed $\mu_0$.  Or, in the notation $X = X^\mu \hat e _{(\mu)}$, that would be the vector field $X$ such that $X^\mu=1$ for $\mu=\mu_0$ and $X^\mu=0$ for $\mu\neq\mu_0$.  This vector field acts on a given function $f$ by $X(f)=\partial_{\mu_0}f$, so it takes the derivative of $f$ in the direction of the coordinate $\mu_0$.  (Note that Carroll's description "partial derivatives of the coordinate functions" is arguably inaccurate; we aren't differentiating the coordinate functions, but rather considering vector fields which are given by partial derivatives in directions corresponding to them.)

Now suppose you have two such vector fields $X=\partial_{\mu_0}$ and $Y=\partial_{\mu_1}$.  The commutator when applied to a function $f$ then gives $$[X,Y](f)=\partial_{\mu_0}\partial_{\mu_1}f-\partial_{\mu_1}\partial_{\mu_0}f.$$  But that's $0$, just from the multivariable calculus fact that partial derivatives commute.

---

It is perhaps more enlightening to see an example where the commutator is *not* zero, to see what's special about the case above.  Let's just consider vector fields on $\mathbb{R}$, where I'll write $\partial_x$ for the ordinary derivative.  Consider two vector fields $X=\partial_x$ and $Y=x\partial_x$.  That is, to compute $X(f)$ you just take the derivative $f'$ and to compute $Y(f)$ you compute the derivative and then multiply by $x$.  We then have $$X(Y(f))=X(xf')=f'+xf''$$ where we get two terms since we needed to use the product rule to differentiate $xf'$.  On the other hand, $$Y(X(f))=Y(f')=xf''.$$  So the difference is $$[X,Y](f)=f'=X(f).$$  In other words, $[X,Y]=X$.  Here the commutator became nonzero because of the coefficient $x$ that $Y$ had, which made us use the product rule when calculating $X(Y(f))$ but not when calculating $Y(X(f))$.  So the point is that if all your vector fields are just partial derivatives with no coefficients to multiply by, this sort of thing doesn't happen and everything commutes.

Comment: Thank you for the additional counter example. Very helpful for someone like me, who's studying this for the first time!

Answer (score 1):

Let us work in local coordinates $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, so $T_pM=\text{span}\left(\frac\partial{\partial x_1},\dots,\frac\partial{\partial x_n}\right)$, for $p(x)=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in this local chart. To be more rigorous here, we have $p\in U\subset M$, for $U$ open and diffeomorphism $\varphi:U\to V\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, with $V$ open. $x_i$ are coordinates on $V$ and $\varphi(p)=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

In general, a vector field $X$ in these coordinates looks like 
$$
X(p)=X_i(x)\frac\partial{\partial x_i}.
$$
This means that, in general,
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
[X,Y]f(p)&=X_i(x)\frac\partial{\partial x_i}\left(Y_j(x)\frac\partial{\partial x_j}f(p(x))\right)-Y_i(x)\frac\partial{\partial x_i}\left(X_j(x)\frac\partial{\partial x_j}f(p(x))\right)\\
&=X_i\partial^iY_j\partial^j f - Y_i\partial^iX_j\partial^j f,
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
where a term cancels by the commutivity of partial derivatives.

Sean Carroll  is saying that if we take the vector fields $X$ and $Y$ such that in these coordinates $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent of $x_i$, then the commutator vanishes, which we can see trivially from the above.

Comment: I‘m sorry, I don’t see the connection between your „..such that in these coordinates $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent of $x_i$“ and Carroll‘s „vector fields given by the partial derivatives of coordinate functions“.

Comment: If $X_i$ is independent of $x$ in these coordinates, then when it acts on $f$ all it does is partial differentiation. It's the difference between the operator $\partial_1$ and $x_2\partial_1$.